# How come my bootstrap modal that's wrapped in a conditional opens the first time, but doesn't open the second time?

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-modal

I've been staring at this code for the last 45 minutes and getting stumped. I've thrown a ton of console.logs in the code and it looks like everything is working the way I wrote it, but it's not working in the browser.

Basically I'm using ng-idle to sign the user out after a session expiration. When they are signed out, a modal appears saying "You've been signed out due to inactivity" appears. The $modal.open for this is wrapped inside a conditional.

This modal appears the first time the user is signed out, but the next time after it does not appear, even though if you look at the console.log's it is in fact inside the if statement containing the $modal.open. Here's the html (doubt it's very helpful but you never know) and the code:

```
<div class="modal-dialog session-timeout">
    <h3 style="text-align: center;">You have been logged out due to inactivity.</h3>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin: auto;">OK</button>
</div>


angular.module('app').run(function($rootScope, $state, $modal, Api, User, Cache) {

  $rootScope.$on('IdleTimeout', function() {
    console.log('DING!!!!!!')
    var timedOut = false;
    console.log('line 98', timedOut);
    return Api.get('/users/logout').then(function (response) {
      console.log('INSIDE RETURN');
      Api.setupHeader('');
      _.each(Object.keys(localStorage), function (key, value) {
        Cache.removeItem(key);
        User.currentUser = null;
        $rootScope.$broadcast('sign-out');
      });
      console.log('line 107', timedOut);
      timedOut = true;
      console.log('line 109 ', timedOut);
      if(timedOut === true) {
        console.log('INSIDE IF');
        $modal.open({
          templateUrl: 'logged-out.html',
          windowClass: 'session-timeout'
        });
      }
        $rootScope.isLogin = false;
        $state.go('home.home-index');
        timedOut = false;
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familar with Angular, but I know if you try to open a bootstrap modal it won't work if the containing div has somehow vanished. Are you sure that your view is not re-rendering and therefore the div you think is there is not?

Comment: That sounds like the issue, because the page that it redirects to does in fact get re-rendered once you're signed out. I'm still confused why it would not render it a second time.

Comment: Its some kind of synchonization issue as the conditional is firing before the render completes; I don't know if Angular uses a shadow DOM, but the structure has to be in the DOM before the modal can fire.